# How to scale points in R plot?

Tags: r, plot, scale

I have 40 pairs of birds with each male and female scored for their colour. The colour score is a categorical variable (range of 1 to 9). I would like to plot the frequency of the number of males and female pairs colour combinations. I have to created a 'table' with the number of each combination (1/1, 1/2, 1/3, ... 9/7, 9/8, 9/9), then converted it to a vector called 'Colour_Count'. I would like to use 'Colour_Count' for the 'cex' parameter in the 'plot' to scale the size of each combination of colours. This does not work because of the order the data is read from the table. How do I create a vector with the frequency of each colour combination to scale my plot points?

See data and code below:

```
## Dataset pairs of males and females and their colour classes
Pair_Colours <- structure(list(Male = c(7, 6, 4, 6, 8, 8, 5, 6, 6, 8, 6, 6, 5, 
7, 9, 5, 8, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 3, 9, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 9, 6, 6, 6), Female = c(9, 8, 8, 9, 3, 6, 8, 5, 8, 9, 7, 
3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 
8, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8)), .Names = c("Male", "Female"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
40L))

Pair_Colours[] <- as.data.frame(lapply(Pair_Colours, factor, levels=1:9))

## table of pair colour values (colours 1 to 9 - categoricial variable)
table(Pair_Colours$Male, Pair_Colours$Female)

Colour_Count <-  as.vector(table(Pair_Colours$Male, Pair_Colours$Female)) #<- the problem occurs here

## plot results to visisually look for possible assortative mating by colour
op<-par(mfrow=c(1,1), oma=c(2,4,0,0), mar=c(4,5,1,2), pty = "s")
plot(1,1, xlim = c(1, 9), ylim = c(1, 9), type="n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", las=1, bty="n", cex.lab = 1.75, cex.axis = 1.5, main = NULL, xlab = "Male Colour", ylab = "Female Colour", pty = "s")
axis(1, at = seq(1, 9, by = 1), labels = T, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, tick = TRUE, tck = -0.015, lwd = 1.25, lwd.ticks = 1.25)
axis(2, at = seq(1, 9, by = 1), labels = T, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, tick = TRUE, tck = -0.015, lwd = 1.25, lwd.ticks = 1.25, las =2)
points(Pair_Colours$Male, Pair_Colours$Female, pch = 21, cex = Colour_Count, bg = "darkgray", col = "black", lwd = 1)
```

Comment: You pretty much gave the answer yourself: generate `Colour_Count` in some other fashion so it is in the same order as your data.

Comment: Obviously, in some other fashion, but how?

Comment: this works with `stat_sum` in `ggplot2`, or `plotrix::sizeplot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can summarise your data with function `ddply()` of library plyr and then use this new data frame to plot your data. Counts are in column `V1` of new data frame.

```
library(plyr)
df<-ddply(Pair_Colours,.(Male,Female),nrow)
df
   Male Female V1
1     3      5  1
2     3      6  1
3     4      2  1
4     4      4  3

points(df$Male, df$Female, pch = 21, cex = df$V1, 
               bg = "darkgray", col = "black", lwd = 1)
```

### UPDATE - solution using aggregate

Other possibility is to use function `aggregate()`. First, add new column `N` that contains just values 1. Then with `aggregate()` sum `N` values for each `Male` and `Female` combination.

```
Pair_Colours$N<-1
aggregate(N~Male+Female,data=Pair_Colours,FUN=sum)

   Male Female N
1     4      2 1
2     6      3 1
3     7      3 1
4     8      3 1
5     4      4 3
```

[image]

Comment: +1 `ddply` should have been my first thought. I have been using it *all* morning!

Comment: Thank you this works great. Can you tell me how to do this without using the 'plyr' package? I would like to learn how to do this with the native R commands directly.

Comment: @KeithLarson Added solution with aggregate()